# Rename Button after changing View Controllers

Tags: ios, uibutton

I'm not good at explaining in big paragraphs so hopefully the steps I'm about to say (of which the app will work as) will help my question.

Steps:

1. Open app. View FirstViewController

2. Press Button code-named "initialButton"

3. Switch to SecondViewController

4. Press Button text-named "Select Me"

5. Bounce back to FirstViewController, have initialButton text say "Select Me"

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property IBOutlet UIButton *initalButton;

@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     self.initalButton.titleLabel.text = name;
}
```

SecondViewController.m

```
selectMe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[selectMe setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
[selectMe setTitle:@"Select Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[selectMe addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    

- (void) someMethod: (id)sender {
    if (sender == selectMe) {
         self.selectMe.titleLabel.text = name;
         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

(NSObject) Background.h

```
NSString *name;
```

My intentions is for when the selectMe button is pressed, the app goes back one ViewController and the initalButton 's text displays whatever button was pressed on SecondViewController. Everything in the app is working except for having initialButton displaying the text of the button pressed on the SecondViewController (step 5 from above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is set up a delegate relationship. This allows you to access properties in a previously active ViewController.

I've assumed you'd be using storyboards for this example, but the basic flow is this. Before the segue is performed, `prepareForSegue:sender:` gets called where we first check to see if the segue is working on SecondViewController. If it is, then we are able to go in and access its properties. In this case, the one we want is delegate. By assigning `self` to delegate, this allows us to do whatever we want to properties in FirstViewController while we're still in SecondViewController because we now have a reference to the parent view controller. Cool huh? You can change properties, run method calls, etc. This is really useful stuff and you'll probably be using this a lot.

By the way, you probably want to use UIButton's `setTitle:forState:` method to change the title name.

I don't know if this code will compile as it relies on stuff you've done which I can't see, but you can at least appreciate how it's supposed to work. Good luck!

```
// FirstViewController.h

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

@property IBOutlet UIButton *initialButton;

@end

// FirstViewController.m

#import "SecondViewController.h"

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
     [self.initialButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[SecondViewController class]) {
        SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)viewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
    }
}

// SecondViewController.h

@class FirstViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstViewController *delegate;

@end

// SecondViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    selectMe = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [selectMe setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [selectMe setTitle:@"Select Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selectMe addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
}

- (void) someMethod: (id)sender 
{
    if (sender == selectMe) {
         [self.delegate.initialButton setTitle:selectMe.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped a lot. I ended up changing my app to display the text to a label nearby it because the app goes from 1 -> 2 -> 1 and the Button was blank when viewing it on 1, but I feel in the future if an app goes from 1 -> 2 and needs to do this, this shall work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a delegate relationship between the 2 controllers so that when a button in the second controller is tapped it calls back to the first controller with the selection information before popping. Then the first controller can update its state before being re-shown.